# Parameters of the log-normal from CDF of a composition of $n$ i.i.d

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, lognormal-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. log-normal random variables such that $$\log(X_i)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\ \ \forall i=1,\ldots,n$$

Now let $Y$ be equal to the $\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. It is quite easy to obtain the relation between the corresponding CDFs: $$P(Y<y)=F_Y(y)=1-[1-F_X(y)]^n$$

Is there a closed form to calculate parameters $\mu_y,\sigma_y$ of a log-normal variable $Y$ given parameters $\mu, \sigma$ of a log-normal variable $X$? And vice versa (find $\mu,\sigma$ given $\mu_y,\sigma_y$)?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Roman. Your question is predicated on a falsehood: when $n\gt 1,$ $Y$ does not have a lognormal distribution.  One can compute the geometric mean and geometric sd of $Y$ using numerical methods, if that's what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Many questions on site address the approximation of a sum of independent lognormals by a lognormal (which often works fairly well, even just by matching the first two moments). However, counterexamples where it's clearly *not*  approximately lognormal are not so hard to identify.

Comment: @whuber, Glen_b, thanks for your answers. So, in this example, $F_Y$ is not log-normal? Maybe there is a way to approximate it by one? The ultimate goal is to be able to draw randomly from $Y$ knowing the distribution of $X$, and/or be able to draw randomly from $X$ knowing the distribution of $Y$

Comment: I doubt a lognormal approximation would be very good, especially for large $n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $Y$ is the minimum of $n$ independent samples from a lognormal distribution $X$ with $\ln(X)\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$. Then $Y$ does not have a lognormal distribution, but one can still ask:

*What are the mean and standard deviation of $Y$?*

Using the Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem), there are some expressions which are accurate in the limit. These are complicated enough that I'll only give the mean, using the expressions for the lognormal from table 3.4.4 of *Modelling Extremal Events* by Embrechts, Klupperberg, and Mikosch (1997):

For large $n$, the distribution of $Y$ will be close to a Gumbel distribution with mean $d_n + \gamma c_n$, or
$$e^\mu\left(1+\frac{\gamma\sigma}{\sqrt{2\ln n}}\right)\left( \ln\frac{n^4\ln n}{4\pi}\right)^{\sigma/\sqrt{8 \ln n}}$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's gamma.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, very appreciated 